# What penalty function does elastic net use?

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm trying to get the [penalized](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/index.html) package and [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) to produce the same output. I've managed it, but not in the way I expected.

So far as I understand the documentation, penalized implements the naive lasso with penalty labmda1 |beta| + lambda2|beta|^2. The help file and vignette for glmnet give the penalty as lambda(alpha|beta| + (1 - alpha)|beta|^2 / 2). Note that the last term is divided by 2.

Playing around revealed that I need to scale the penalty parameters in one implementation by the sample size to get the same results in the other implementation

```
library(glmnet)
library(penalized)

# Simulate some data
x <- rmvnorm(1000, mean=rep(0, 50))
y <- 1 / (1 + exp(x[, 1] + x[, 2] + x[, 3] + x[, 4]))
y <- rbinom(1000, prob=y, size=1)

# Set penalty paramters
alpha <- 0.5
lambda <- 0.1
lambda1 <- lambda * alpha * 1000
lambda2 <- lambda * (1 - alpha) / 2 * 1000

gnet <- glmnet(x, y, family="binomial", lambda=lambda, alpha=alpha, standardize=TRUE)
gco <- coef(gnet)
gco[abs(gco[, 1]) > 0, ] # non-zero coefficients

pmod <- penalized(y, x, lambda1=lambda1, lambda2=lambda2, standardize=TRUE)
coef(pmod)
```

The results are similar, but not close enough. However, if I get rid of the factor of 1/2, I get matching answers.

```
lambda2 <- lambda * (1 - alpha) * 1000

gnet <- glmnet(x, y, family="binomial", lambda=lambda, alpha=alpha, standardize=TRUE)
gco <- coef(gnet)
gco[abs(gco[, 1]) > 0, ] # non-zero coefficients

pmod <- penalized(y, x, lambda1=lambda1, lambda2=lambda2, standardize=TRUE)
coef(pmod)
```

What's going on?

Comment: Looks like you got the results to match after some fiddling around. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the documentation for glmnet says to divide the ridge penalty by 2

Comment: I'm not seeing in the penalized documentation any formal definition of the L2 penalty, actually. It may _also_ divide the penalty by 2, so if you do the division yourself, you'd actually be dividing by 4.

Comment: Jelle J. Goeman (2010) L1 penalized estimation in the Cox proportional hazards model, Biometrical Journal, 52
  (1) 70-84.  It appears to be the equation at the top of page 83, described as "(naive) elastic net" and with no division by 2.

Comment: Trevor Hastie was kind enough to answer an email asking about this: "Have a look at the glmnet vignette harry. 
E.g. For squared error we standardize y before fitting the path. 
There is an equivalence, so if you are careful you will find the mapping. Our focus is fitting the path, so the particular formulation used is less important"

Comment: The log likelihood is divided by 2 in the implementation of glmnet, which gets eliminated when the derivative is taken (in the least squares case, I mean). Similarly, when taking the derivative of the penalty function, the term 1/2 gets eliminated in the derivative. So presumably it's there for algebraic convenience. See equations (1) and (4) of Friedman, Hastie, Tibshirani, 2010.